# How can i pass field names dynamicly to the a component

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am trying to build a reusable component based on the mat-select / mat-option component from Angular Material.

My template looks like this

```html
<mat-select
    #select  
    placeholder="Tract List"
    formControlName ="multiselect"
    multiple>
    <div class="select-all">
        <mat-checkbox 
            (change)="toggleAllSelection()">{{selectAllText}}</mat-checkbox>
    </div>
    <mat-option (click)="optionClick()" *ngFor="let List of  data" [value]="List.guid">{{ List.name}}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

What I am looking for is a way to pass in the actual **[value]** field and whats displayed which is currently **{{List.name}}** I ideally want to be able to specify the name of the field to use or even be able to specify a string like  **List.text2 + " - " + List.id**

How can I achieve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several ways to achieve this, but the easiest to explain and understand is with a simple **'property binding'** between componets:
https://angular.io/guide/property-binding

You can do a component with your code (for instance, with the name 'app-mymultiselect'), and add to it two *Input* attributes (*data* and *fieldNameToShow*) :

```
import { Component } from "@angular/core";
...
@Component({
    selector: 'app-mymultiselect',
    templateUrl: './mymultiselect.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./mymultiselect.component.scss']
})
export class MymultiselectComponent{

@Input() data!: any[]; // Type it depending on your data list elements
@Input() fieldNameToShow: string = 'name'; // name or id or whatever you like by default
...
```

And in its HTML, something like this:

```
<mat-option (click)="optionClick()" *ngFor="let List of data" [value]="List.guid">{{ List[fieldNameToShow] }}</mat-option>
</mat-select>
```

Then, for use it in any of your components, you only have to add in the HTML something like this:

```
<app-mymultiselect [data]="youArrayOfElements" [fieldNameToShow]="fieldNameToShow"></app-mymultiselect>
```

Being its value in the *ts* file:

- 'youArrayOfElements' a variable/attribute with the list of object you want the select to show.
- 'fieldNameToShow' a variable/attribute string, with the object's name you want to show (for instance, fieldNameToShow = 'id');

Comment: Thanks, that works, but how would i go about to create something like List.text2 + " - " + List.id as i can only specify one fieldname ?

Comment: I'm glad it worked. You can pass the amount of variables you want (for instance, with fieldNameToShow1, fieldNameToShow2,..fieldNameToShown, treat them in the same way as my example, an @Input for any of them in your component, and writing <app-mymultiselect [data]="youArrayOfElements" fieldNameToShow1='name' fieldNameToShow2='id' fieldNameToShow3='tex2'..> etc) . Or even you can put just an array with all of them or an object.

Comment: I think we are talking about different things. If i have {{ List[fieldNameToShow] }}part in my *ngFor i can specify the field name and that works fine. But what if i want to display List.text2 + " - " + List.id in that part ? I dont know when and if i will use a single value to display or if i want to display 2 with some string between or end etc. You last example works if i want multiple fields and i know lets say its 2 and i pass 2 in but i am looking for a more flexible way since it will be a reusable component ?

Comment: Not at all! :) As I said in the previous answer, you could pass all the fields you want to show in your HTML as an array, and then iterate it. Something like this: <app-mymultiselect [data]="youArrayOfElements" fieldsToShow="['text2','id']>, and then in your reusable component something like: @Input fieldsToShow: string[] = []; and iterate it in the HTML, or maybe build in the *ts* a new variable with a foreach: public mynewstringtoshow=''; fieldsToShow.forEach( _itemToShow => { mynewstringtoshow = mynewstringtoshow + ' - ' + _itemToShow }  and show it in the HTML just {{ mynewstringtoshow  }}